# Repeating group names in Pathauto path

Tags: organic-groups, path-aliases

My pathauto patterns are giving me trouble with organic groups. All books are contained within groups.

Book_main_page shows as:

> Group_name/Book_main_page

A child of Book_main_page shows as:

> Group_name/Group_name/Book_main_page/Child

A child of the child page shows as:

> Group_name/Group_name/Group_name/Book_main_page/Child/Child_of_child

How do I get rid of the repeated group names?

The group content type "book page" has a "Pattern for all Book page paths" of:

> [node:og-group-ref]/[node:book:parent:url:path]/[node:book:title]

The group type "Group" has a "Pattern for all Group Paths" of:

> [node:og-group-ref]/[node:title]

My page uses one group content type "book page" (from the books module) and one group type "group".

Answer (score 0):

For the "book page" content type, try using the path:

```
[node:og-group-ref:title]/[node:book:parents:join-path]/[node:book:title]
```